# Policy for AWS EMR full access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to attach a policy to a user so it has full access to EMR in AWS. Previously, I was able to do that using the "AmazonElasticMapReduceFullAccess" policy, but this is getting depreciated and is suggested to replace with "AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2". Using the latest policy however I get the following error when trying to create an EMR cluster :

`Error fetching Amazon EMR releases You do not have permission to use Amazon EMR API listReleaseLabels. Request permission from your administrator.`

Do I need to attach any additional policies besides the "AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2" ?